# Can work be negative?

Tags: calculus

> Which of the following is the work done by a non-constant force $F (x) = x$ moving an object along the $x$‑axis from $2$ to $0$?

I was given this problem. The correct answer is $-2$ because the integral is set up like: $\int^0_2$. But, can  work really be negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, work can be negative. Work is the amount of energy put into a system by the object described by the field $F$. If work is positive energy is added, if work is negative then energy was actually taken out of the system. Both of these things occur in nature.

Comment: So it means that it was 2 work taken out of the system

Answer (score 0):

Yes, work can be negative. If I lift a book with mass $1$ kg a distance $10$ m (working "against" the gravitational field of the earth), then I do $10$ N of work. The gravitational field, reciprocally, does $-10$ N of work on the book. When I put the book back in its original position, I now do $-10$ N of work.